# How to use RewriteBase to change `localhost` to `localhost/subdir`?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old .htaccess file I'm trying to get working again but I don't recall how I got it to work originally.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
```

It is located like so:

```
/ localhost
  / site
    / subfolder
    / subfolder2
    / subfolder3
    / index.php
    / page.php
    / .htaccess
```

My website's entry point is `localhost/site/index.php` and contains links to other pages. If I click on a link, say, `./page`, it brings me to `localhost/page` instead of `localhost/site/page.php`. Note the subdirectory is ignored and the extension is taken literal when RewriteBase should have interpreted it as a `.php`.

I've tried changing `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /site/` and it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in `site/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

In site root .htacess you need to put this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ site/$1.php [L]
```

PS: It would be better to fix your relative links by adding this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/site/" />`

Answer (score 0):

An explanation...

> If I click on a link, say, `./page`, it brings me to `localhost/page` instead of `localhost/site/page.php`

It would have internally rewritten the request to `/page.php` (in the document root), which would have presumably resulted in a 404. This is because of the `RewriteBase /` directive - which provides the URL-prefix for relative path substitutions, ie. `$1.php`.

> Note the subdirectory is ignored ...

Because the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/site` subdirectory, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* only captures the part of the URL-path that comes after this. So, for example, if you request `localhost/site/page` (the resolved URL-path from your *relative* `./page` link) then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* captures `page` (the value of the `$1` backreference), which is rewritten to `page.php`, to which the `RewriteBase` is prefixed to become `/page.php` (in the document root).

> I've tried changing `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /site/` and it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Yes. In fact, this is all you *needed* to do.

**Or**, preferably, remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely (which is what @anubhava did in his answer), since the `.htaccess` file resides in the same directory. In the absence of the `RewriteBase` directive, the default action for relative path substitutions is to add back the directory-prefix (ie. the file system path of the `/site` directory). So, given a request for `/site/page` (from the `./page` link) it would naturally rewrite to `/site/page.php` without having to explicitly include the `/site` subdirectory.

Either way, changing the `RewriteBase` directive, in this case, *must* have done something. If not, then you were probably seeing a cached response.

> My website's entry point is `localhost/site/index.php`

Providing the `/site` subdirectory is part of the visible URL, as you suggest, then the additional `.htaccess` file in the site root is not required (as in @anubhava's answer). Either way, you wouldn't need both.